# Liberación memoria proceso vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access

Buenas a todos!
Tengo una aplicación en .net en la que exporto los datos de varias tablas y el formato de un Excel a varias hojas de otro excel.
En dicha exportación, voy copiando desde un template el formato de las celdas al Excel en el que a continuación importo los datos de las tablas.
Dicho proceso es el siguiente:

```
    Public Sub Copy_Paste(workbook_copy As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, sheet_copy As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, range_copy As String, workbook_paste As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, sheet_paste As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, Row_paste As Integer, Column_paste As Integer)
    workbook_copy.Activate()
    With sheet_copy
        .Select()
        .Range(range_copy).Copy()
    End With

    workbook_paste.Activate()
    With sheet_paste
        .Select()
        .Cells(Row_paste, Column_paste).select()
        .Paste()
    End With
End Sub
```

El problema que me surge es que debido al número de veces que repito este proceso llega un momento en el que se colapsa por saturación ya que creo que va guardando el copy-pega que va realizando. He probado con 'Clipboard.Clear()' y con el 'GC.collect() pero sigue produciéndose la excepción:

> Ocurrió DisconnectedContext
>   Message: El Asistente para la depuración administrada 'DisconnectedContext' ha detectado un problema.
>   Información adicional: Transition into COM context 0x88ceb8 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: System call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)).

Se que el problema es la saturación de información almacenada ya que el otro proceso que tengo (*exportación de los datos de las tablas al Excel*) me pasaba lo mismo, pero como utilizaba un objeto al finalizar su ejecución lo eliminaba y este espacio de memoria se liberaba pero en este caso estoy perdido.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Supongo que llamas al método `Copy_Paste` en un bucle o algo asi? Porque en principio, el código que muestras es correcto, al usar `With` se debería llamar al `Dispose` de los objetos al acabar el bloque. De todas maneras, Interop es muy delicado y suele dar problemas de este tipo...

Comment: Ninguno de esos metodos implementa dispose no?

Comment: Mira este link, esta en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects

Comment: Muchas gracias por el Link Luis!!!     Gracias a él pude seguir investigando y encontré la solución!!!     Después del segundo bloque With añadí la siguiente línea de código: **System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()**   Hace que vaya mucho más rápido y no se colapsa.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema. Tomo los datos de una base de datos y creo el archivo xls. Cuando hay 600 líneas está bien, los tiempos son razonables pero si llego a más de 3000 líneas se necesitan más de dos horas. Comienza rápido pero luego se ralentiza hacia el final. ¿Has encontrado una solución?

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/298370)